# creating a docker bridge network for a virtual sub interface

Tags: networking, docker

I have a docker host with 1 physical network interface. I want to have a docker container connected to a network that is bridged to a second IP. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is, but here is what I tried so far.

I created a sub interface with

```
ifconfig enp0s31f6:0 192.168.2.32
```

Then created a new docker network like this:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.2.32/24 --gateway=192.168.2.32 second
```

then started a new container with --net=second 
The problem is that I cannot ping google.com from within containers that are on the "second" docker network.

```
[
{
    "Name": "second",
    "Id": "1540526cbab982cd86892bdbb1b2ac20f26964824469ba890c40b3615e2bfa6d",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "192.168.2.0/24",
                "Gateway": "192.168.2.32"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {}
}
]
```

running "ping -I 192.168.2.32 www.google.com" on the host works.

The goal is to have the containers accessible with one IP, and the rest of the host accessible with another.

Comment: I imagine that you don't need an IP alias for this. After all, ip alias is property of the host. What you want, perhaps, instead is to get docker to bridge your host network interface with container's network interface. Container's if gets own MAC address, and container is responsible to set IP address on it, be it static or dhcp.